# Error: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I run  `flutter run --release`:

- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google

---

MacOS 14.4 (Apple Silicon) • Android Studio 2023.2.1 • Java 17
Flutter 3.19.4 • Dart 3.3.2 • DevTools 2.31.1

---

`settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }
}

plugins {
    //id "com.google.gms" version "8.7.0" apply false
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false
    //id "com.android.library" version "8.7.0" apply false
}

//rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'

include ":app"
```

---

`gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip
```

---

`android/build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no version 8.7.0 for the Android Gradle plugin ([Google repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.android.application.gradle.plugin#com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin)).

Choose the latest available, 8.3.1:

```
id "com.android.application" version "8.3.1" apply false
```