Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources: unity
I tried to get output from the android project but I got this error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'a\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\build.gradle' line: 6

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:



Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.1')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
Google
MavenRepo


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
My version of unity is 2023.2.5f1
JDK version is jdk-11
NDK version is android-ndk-r23b
SDK API level 32
settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        **ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include ':launcher', ':unityLibrary'
**INCLUDES**

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        **ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}


Did you check these pages? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099487/plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-2-0-apply-false-was-not-f — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78230724/error-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-8-7-0-apply-false-wa — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053336/android-gradle-plugin-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-1-3 — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990052/plugin-id-com-android-application-version-7-3-0-apply-false-was-not-f

yes but not work

Please share your settings.gradle file.

I'd verify that you get the same error when running Gradle from the command line. Sometimes the IDE can have errors creep into its caches.
